# What is the exact difference between Polymer "reflectToAttribute" and "notify"?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

The [Polymer properties object](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties) supports two different keys that I don't quite understand the difference between, `reflectToAttribute` and `notify`.

`reflectToAttribute` says that the attribute on the host node will change when the value changes.

`notify` says it makes the property available for two-way binding.

Aren't these sort of the same thing? If you have `notify` set to `true`, then is there any reason that you would still need `reflectToAttribute`?

Could someone explain to me exactly how these keys relate to one another? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`reflectToAttribute` is to get the attribute added to the DOM. This way you can for example use it as selector in CSS

`notify` is as mentioned in your question for two-way binding.

These are two entirely different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If we "reflect" a `prop`, it will appear in that component's element tag as such:

`<component prop></component>`

As mentioned, we could use the presence of that attribute to conditionally style the component in our style section: `:host([prop]) div { background-color: green }`

In **litElement**, we simply write: `reflect: true` in the property definition (rather than `reflectToAttribute`).

As you know, if we use `notify: true` on a child property, then changes in its value will also occur in its corresponding parent property (2-way binding).

In **litElement**, `notify` doesn't exist.  Instead, to pass info back to the parent, you can dispatch a custom event in the child and listen for it in the parent.

In Polymer, I initially thought that in order to notify a parent of a change, we had to reflect the prop as an attribute, but this isn't the case.